# sycl vector types are not marked as device copyable

Tags: c++, intel, sycl, dpc++

This line:

```
static_assert(
    sycl::is_device_copyable<sycl::float3>::value,
    "The vector types should be copyable."
);
```

Fails with the static assert error for all vector types in sycl. This is using:

```
dpcpp -v
Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler 2022.1.0 (2022.1.0.20220316)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin-llvm
```

with the command line using `-fsycl`.

Shouldn't `sycl::vec` vector types be marked as device copyable?

---

I am writing a USM manager structure, so my workaround is to just use:

```
template <typename... Types>
constexpr bool are_all_types_device_copyable()
{
    return (
        (sycl::is_device_copyable<Types>::value ||
         is_sycl_vec_v<Types>)&&...
    );
}
```

Where `is_sycl_vec` is:

```
template <typename>
struct is_sycl_vec : public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename dataT, int numElements>
struct is_sycl_vec<sycl::vec<dataT, numElements>> : public std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_sycl_vec_v = is_sycl_vec<T>::value;
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with a complete sample reproducer code and steps to reproduce the issue so we can investigate more on our end?

Comment: @Varsha-Intel What more are you looking for? Take any sycl program compiled with dpcpp. For example anything from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/explore-dpcpp-samples-from-intel/top.html). Add the first line in the question anywhere in any sample and it will fail to compile. This is what a `static_assert` is for. I am just surprised because i would have thought sycl::vector types should be device copyable by default.

Answer (score -1):

A std::vector (for any T) is not device copyable since it is not trivially copyable. Because it's user-provided (as opposed to implicitly-defined).

Please find the below link,
https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#sec::device.copyable

Comment: The question is `Shouldn't sycl::vec vector types be marked as device copyable?` **sycl** not *std*. std::vector i understand is not device copyable, but `sycl::vec<T, size>` should be, but it is not.